# Splitting a SQL column into 2 based on its values

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
declare  
        @PharmTransDateKey int


set @PharmTransDateKey = 20160630

select 
    ds.StoreName, 
    case when dro.NetCount < 0 then 'Previous Period Adj'
        else 'Todays Sales'
    end as Category,
    sum(ClaimAmount) as ThirdPartyDue
from
    Final.FactRxBusinessEffectiveDay f 
        inner join Final.DimRxOutcome dro 
            on  f.RxOutcomeKey = dro.RxOutcomeKey
        inner join Final.DimStore ds
            on  ds.StoreKey = f.StoreKey and
                ds.SourceChainKey = 254 
where  
    PharmTransDateKey =  @PharmTransDateKey and
    dro.NetCount <> 0
group by 
    ds.StoreName,
    case when dro.NetCount < 0 then 'Previous Period Adj'
        else 'Todays Sales'
    end  
order by 1,2,3
```

Which outputs this:

[image]

I would like to use the only two possible values in the `Category` column and make them their own columns.  The table below is what I am shooting for.

[image]

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare  @PharmTransDateKey int
set @PharmTransDateKey = 20160630

SELECT
    ds.StoreName
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN dro.NetCount < 0 THEN ClaimAmount ELSE 0 END) AS 'Previous Period Adj'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN dro.NetCount < 0 THEN 0 ELSE ClaimAmount END) AS 'Todays Sales'
FROM
    Final.FactRxBusinessEffectiveDay f 
    inner join Final.DimRxOutcome dro 
        on  f.RxOutcomeKey = dro.RxOutcomeKey
    inner join Final.DimStore ds
        on  ds.StoreKey = f.StoreKey and
            ds.SourceChainKey = 254 
WHERE
    PharmTransDateKey =  @PharmTransDateKey and
    dro.NetCount <> 0
GROUP BY
    ds.StoreName
```

I would have written `PIVOT` but really you would be pivoting a query that you can just modify and `SUM` `CASE STATEMENTS` and get to your answer far simpler and faster.  There is no need to have an intermediary query between the one you are showing and your final desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can split a column based on its value by joining a table with itself with different alias.

Say you have table Sales with fields shopId,dept,sales

You can do:

```
select 
    s1.shopId, 
    s1.dept, s1.sales grocery_sales, 
    s2.dept, s2.sales bakery_sales
from 
    Sales s1, Sales s2
where 
    s1.shopId = s2.shopId
and s1.dept="grocery" 
and s2.dept="bakery"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your query to calculate the fields instead like this:

```
select 
    ds.StoreName, 
    sum(case when dro.NetCount < 0 then claimamount end) 'Previous Period Adj'
    sum(case when dro.NetCount >= 0 then claimamount end) 'Todays Sales'
from
    Final.FactRxBusinessEffectiveDay f 
        inner join Final.DimRxOutcome dro 
            on  f.RxOutcomeKey = dro.RxOutcomeKey
        inner join Final.DimStore ds
            on  ds.StoreKey = f.StoreKey and
                ds.SourceChainKey = 254 
where  
    PharmTransDateKey =  @PharmTransDateKey and
    dro.NetCount <> 0
group by 
    ds.StoreName,
order by 1
```